# Laravel how to execute a command in crontab from a shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've tried this:

```
php /home/public_html/artisan command:foo test
```

and I get this error:

```
No input file specified.
```

how can I get the exact path to my artisan to execute this??

Comment: Where have you stored that file?

Comment: as I see from my ftp manager is /home/public_html/artisan, but why I get no input file specified?

Comment: FTP? Please look-up the path in the shell, the path shown in your FTP client can be misleading. Instead use `realpath .` or `pwd` in the shell to get the full path of the current directory.

Comment: oh, looks like there are only ftp access, no ssh :(

Comment: well then you should use your *local* path to artisan and call it locally because you can not call it remotely. either local shell (terminal, cmd) or the remote shell (ssh). -- http://laravel.com/docs/artisan

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
/usr/local/bin/php public_html/artisan foo
```